# How to set initial data for CKEditor5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I can't find a simple example on how to set initial data in CKEditor 5.

In some SO questions, it's said that we should use `setData` API. But those examples are AJAX based.

In CKEditor 4, I would simply set the `value` of the `textarea` and that was it.

In CKEditor 5, the HTML is not `textarea` but a simple `<div>`.

I tried to put the content inside the `<div>` and it did not work.

I also can't find an example in the docs.

So, how can I set initial data in CKEditor 5?

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the `initialData` field in your config object during initialization. [Doc reference](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html#member-initialData)